# How to add linewidth property to MGLFillStyleLayer in mapbox ios sdk?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have to add polygon features in the 'MGLFillStyleLayer' with 'MGLPolygonFeature' but the problem is I can't change the outline width.

Comment: Don't forget to show what you've tried / the current code you have set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line width for a `MGLFillStyleLayer` currently cannot be changed. The suggested workaround is to use the same source to create a [`MGLLineStyleLayer`](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.7.3/Classes/MGLLineStyleLayer.html), then insert the line layer above the fill layer.

I can add a line layer to [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/fill-pattern/) with the following code:

```
    let lineLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "line-layer", source: source)
    lineLayer.lineWidth = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 5)
    lineLayer.sourceLayerIdentifier = "drone-restrictions-3f6lsg"

    if let cityLabels = style.layer(withIdentifier: "place-city-sm") {
        style.insertLayer(layer, below: cityLabels)
        style.insertLayer(lineLayer, above: layer)
    }
```