# How to Change Line Width in MapBox for IOS

Tags: ios, mapbox

How do I change the line width in a MGLLineStyleLayer?

```
//This is to change the color of the line
let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "trails-path", source: trails)
layer.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.brown)
mapView.style?.addLayer(layer)
```

[image: MGLStyleValue doesn't seem to work]

MGLStyleValue doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried and what didn't work

Comment: I tried using lineStyle.lineWidth = MLGStyleValue(rawValue: 4.0) but "MLGStyleValue" doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please update your question with that information. What was the results?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636433/how-to-add-linewidth-property-to-mglfillstylelayer-in-mapbox-ios-sdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using v4.0.0 or later of the Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS. The Maps SDK adopted `NSExpression` for styling in v4.0.0.

It looks like you want to use:

```
lineStyle.lineWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 5)
```

For more information about migrating to expressions, see the [Migrating to Expressions](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/4.3.0/migrating-to-expressions.html) guide.